# Criando TEdit em tempo real e ação OnEnter

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe6

Ultimamente estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo móvel e necessito criar uma `TEdit` em tempo real com a função de ação pré-definida. Até o momento consigo criar, mas sem a função `OnEnter` de ação.

Aqui está o código:

```
procedure CriarEdit;
var
  tipo:TForm;
  edit: TEdit;
begin
  tipo := Form1;
  edit := TEdit.Create(tipo);
  edit.Name := 'cp1';
  edit.Height := 30;
  edit.Width := 81.00001;
  edit.Enabled := true;
  edit.Visible := true;
  edit.ReadOnly := true;
  edit.Parent := tipo;
  edit.HitTest := true;
  // edit.OnEnter := executaOutraProcedure(); -- aqui dá problemas
end;
```

Como posso estar definindo a propriedade OnEnter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não estou familiarizado com desenvolvimento mobile ainda, nem mesmo com Delphi. Mas a associação de um método de um evento tem que ser feito sem o parênteses.

Assim:

```
edit.OnEnter := executaOutraProcure;
```

Dessa forma a associção será aceita.
O que não pode esquecer é que a assinatura do método deve ser a mesma.

Escrevento o método em um escopo executável, como uma procure, usando os parênteses significa que você está forçando a execução dela.

Em uma ***VCL Forms Application***, adicionando um `TEdit` ao `Form` e criando associando um método ao evento `OnEnter`, ele cria uma assinatura assim:

```
procedure Form1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
```

Ou seja, seu método precisar ter esse parâmetro o `Sender`, do tipo `TObject`.
Lembrando que precisa ser um método de classe, e não apenas uma procedure qualquer.

---

#### Um pouco mais de informação:

O evento `OnEnter` de um `TEdit` é do tipo `TNotifyEvent`.
`TNotifyEvent` está declarado em um dos acenstrais de `TEdit`, o `TWinControl` e o tipo esta declarado assim:

```
type
  TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```